# Creating a list of found Mifare Tags with arduino?

Tags: arduino, nfc, rfid, arduino-uno

I am working with an Arduino Uno and an adaFruit PN532 board.  The goal is to be able to create a list of MiFare Cards currently in range of the NFC Shield.

I am having trouble figuring out the best way to write this logic, as the board only seems to detect one card per loop.

I can place two cards on the board and it sees them both but only one per loop. so how would i go about creating a current list of what is currently in range

**my loop:**

```
 void loop()
{

  Serial.println("--------------------Loop begin-------------------");
  uint8_t success;
  uint8_t uid[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };  // Buffer to store the returned UID
  uint8_t uidLength;                        // Length of the UID (4 or 7 bytes depending on ISO14443A card type)

  uint8_t index =0;  
  // Wait for an ISO14443A type cards (Mifare, etc.).  When one is found
  // 'uid' will be populated with the UID, and uidLength will indicate
  // if the uid is 4 bytes (Mifare Classic) or 7 bytes (Mifare Ultralight)
  success = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, uid, &uidLength);

   if (success) {

    // Display some basic information about the card
    Serial.println("Found an ISO14443A card");
    Serial.print("  UID Length: ");Serial.print(uidLength, DEC);Serial.println(" bytes");
    Serial.print("  UID Value: ");
    nfc.PrintHex(uid, uidLength);
    Serial.println("");

  }

   Serial.println("************************Loop END*********************");
}
```

**and here is the serial monitor out when both cards in range:**

> --------------------Loop begin-------------------
>
> Found an ISO14443A card
>   UID Length: 4 bytes
>   UID Value: 0x13 0x99 0x1C 0xD4
>
> ************************Loop END*********************
>
> --------------------Loop begin-------------------
>   Found an ISO14443A card
>   UID Length: 4 bytes
>   UID Value: 0x13 0x34 0x27 0xD4
>
> ************************Loop END*********************

Answer (score 0):

You need some state (something like an array of a struct with ID and length fields) **outside** of the loop to store your (potentially multiple) UIDs. Looking at the [code for readPassiveTargetID](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C/blob/master/Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C.cpp) I would think it's likely to be be a bit random which card ID is returned if there is more than one of them.

I imagine you'll need to keep reading IDs, checking the array to see if you've seen it before and storing it if not.  Then after some time (or the array overflows, or some other trigger) you can print out the IDs you have seen "recently" and reset the array to being empty (eg by clearing the length field)